# What's the point of a label tag for a select tag?

Tags: html, select, label

(HTML) I realize that the label tag for an input tag puts the cursor in the field when you click the label, but it doesn't seem to do anything for a select tag. Is it even useful for a select tag or necessary for anything?

Answer (score 2):

Clicking on a `label` element focuses on the associated control even when the control is a `select` element. This is a real effect, though it is unclear whether there is much use for it (unlike for radio buttons and checkboxes, which tend to be tiny and pose problems to people with motoric disabilities).

In screen readers and assistive software, the `label` markup can help in different ways, as described in the WCAG 2.0 document [Labels or Instructions: Understanding SC 3.3.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/NOTE-UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20-20140916/minimize-error-cues.html). In particular: “When label elements are associated with input elements the label is spoken by screen readers when the field receives focus and users with impaired motor control are helped by a larger clickable area for the control, since clicking on the label or the control will activate the control.” So for example, if the user moves around using the Tab key (to focus on a control), the browser or assistive software may react to the focusing by speaking the associated label.

Answer (score 0):

It tells people what they are selecting.

Consider the difference between:

```
<label for="a"> Your allergies </label>
<select multiple id="a">
    <option>Cats
    <option>Dogs
</select>

<label for="b"> Your favourite animals </label>
<select multiple id="b">
    <option>Cats
    <option>Dogs
</select>
```

Now remove the labels and try to fill in the correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

There may not be any additional functionality in tying a label to a `select`, but it adds semantic meaning to the label by associating them.  In addition, it provides context for assistance software like screen readers that may be used by users with visual disabilities.